# Different behavior for NestedScrollView vs. ScrollView

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1 and the 22.2.1 support design library.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a simple project with the activity main layout containing a
   NestedScrollView holding many EditText views, enough that will
   require scrolling to view all of them.
2. Start the application, and notice that you can scroll fine (do not touch any of the edit texts at this point).  All edit texts
   should be able to be scrolled to.
3. Touch any of the edit texts to bring up the keyboard.
4. Try scrolling around again.  The scroll area has been restricted, and you cannot view all other edit texts.

Comment: How can we know your problem without your code?

Comment: In other words, post your layout code :)

Comment: show me the code..